# print dir path after matching its name with wildcards

Tags: awk, path, wildcard

Have been stuck with this little puzzle. Thank you in advance for helping.

I have a directory path and would like print its path after match.

like

```
echo /Users/user/Documents/terraform-shared-infra/services/history_book_test | awk -F "terraform-|tfRepo-" '{print $(NF)}'

echo /Users/user/Documents/tfRepo-shared-infra/services/history_book_test | awk -F "terraform-|tfRepo-" '{print $(NF)}'
```

output:

```
shared-infra/services/history_book_test

shared-infra/services/history_book_test
```

When i try to add wildcard in **terraform-*** it doesn't work.

I would like to print path after match with terraform-* or tfRepo*.
Like:

```
services/history_book_test
services/history_book_test/../.. so on.
```

with sed:

```
echo /Users/user/Documents/terraform-shared-infra/services/history_book_test | sed 's|.*terraform.\([^/]*\)/.*|\1|'
shared-infra
```

Have tried different ways with awk and grep but no luck. Any leads or idea that I can try. Please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing [regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) with [globbing patterns](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13). Both have wildcards and look similar but have quite different meanings and uses. regexps are used by text processing tools like grep, sed, and awk to match text in input strings while globbing patterns are used by shells to match file/directory names. For example, `foo*` in a regexp means `fo` followed by zero or more additional `o`s while `foo*` in a globbing pattern means `foo` followed by zero or more other characters (which in a regexp would be `foo.*`). So never just say "wildcard", say "regexp wildcard" or "globbing wildcard" for clarity.

This might be what you're trying to do, using a sed that has a `-E` arg to enable EREs, e.g. GNU or BSD sed:

```
$ sed -E 's:.*/(terraform|tfRepo)-[^/]*/::' file
services/history_book_test
services/history_book_test
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(".*/(terraform|tfRepo)-[^/]*/","")} 1' file
services/history_book_test
services/history_book_test
```

Regarding your attempt with sed `sed 's|.*terraform.\([^/]*\)/.*|\1|'` - if you're going to use a char other than `/` for the delimiters, don't use a char like `|` that's a regexp or backreference metachar as at best that obfuscates your code, pick some char that's always literal instead, e.g. `:`.

Comment: thank you very much @edmorton sir. Also for clear explanation.